# hide checkbox border in html/javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way to hide the square border of a checkbox in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not cross-browser, no.

You can replace checkboxes entirely with custom controls that emulate checkbox behaviour using JavaScript, though. [Here's an example with jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-checkbox/).